# Java Play2 with CDN

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, cdn

I am using a CDN (amazon cloudfront) and I am trying to configure play to work with a CDN

```
GET    xxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="",file)
```

The problem with this approach is that my image url looks like this

```
http://localhost:9000/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/images/Ascalon_Wall_Ruins.jpg
```

I would need to remove the `http://localhost:9000/`

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: See also http://www.jamesward.com/2012/08/08/edge-caching-with-play2-heroku-cloudfront (though things have slightly changed with `versioned` assets).

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use Play's `router` for building external links, instead you can just prefix it with domain, ie. if you're storing paths in your model as `images/Ascalon_Wall_Ruins.jpg` in its `file` field, you can just put it directly in template:

```
@for(item <- itemsList){
    <img src="http://domain.tld/@item.file" />
}
```

Of course you can also create additional method in your model's class to deliver `ready-to-use` path.

Comment: Mark the question as answered then.

Answer (score 3):

I solved my problem like this:

```
package Config;

public class CDN {
    private final static String url = "http://yourcdnurl.net/;

    public static String createUrl(String s) {
        return url + s;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href= "@Config.CDN.createUrl("stylesheets/bootstrap.css")">
```

Comment: TIP: Use single quotas for href ie: `href='@createUrl("file.css")'` it's allowed in W3C specs since maaany years and at least it doesn't fool your IDE. Quotas for params while calling some Java (or Scala) methods in Play templates must be double.